# ValueError at /admin/marketing/marketingpreference/add/, too many values to unpack (expected 2)

Tags: python, django, python-3.x, django-models, django-rest-framework

I'm try to my User model email in Marketing app.  I was following the marketing app tutorial from video. but in that video that program doesn't show error. when i was write same program it's show error:

**ValueError at /admin/marketing/marketingpreference/add/ 
too many values to unpack (expected 2)**

```
from django.db import models
from django.db.models.signals import post_save, pre_save
from .utils import Mailchimp
from accounts.models import User


class MarketingPreference(models.Model):
    user =models.OneToOneField(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    subscribed = models.BooleanField(default=True)
    mailchimp_subscribed = models.NullBooleanField(blank=True)
    mailchimp_msg= models.TextField(null=True, blank=True)
    timestamp =models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    update =models.DateTimeField(auto_now= True)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.user.email

def marketing_pref_update_receiver(sender, instance, *args, **kwargs):
    if instance.subscribed != instance.mailchimp_subscribed:
        if instance.subscribed:
            status_code, response_data = Mailchimp().unsubscribe(instance.user.email)
        else:
            status_code, response_data = Mailchimp().subscribe(instance.user.email)

        if response_data['status'] == 'subscribed' :
            instance.subscribed = True
            instance.mailchimp_subscribed = True
            instance.mailchimp_msg = response_data
        else:
            instance.subscribed = False
            instance.mailchimp_subscribed = False
            instance.mailchimp_msg = response_data


pre_save.connect(marketing_pref_update_receiver, sender=MarketingPreference)



def make_marketing_pref_receiver(sender, instance, created, *args, **kwargs):
    if created:
        MarketingPreference.objects.get_or_create(user=instance)

post_save.connect(make_marketing_pref_receiver, sender=User)
```

and my utils.py

```
class Mailchimp(object):
    def __init__(self):
        super(Mailchimp, self).__init__()
        self.key = MAILCHIMP_API_KEY
        self.api_url = "https://{dc}.api.mailchimp.com/3.0".format(dc=MAILCHIMP_DATA_CENTER)
        self.list_id = MAILCHIMP_EMAIL_LIST_ID
        self.list_endpoint = '{api_url}/lists/{list_id}'.format(api_url=self.api_url, list_id=self.list_id)

    def get_member_endpoint(self):
        return self.list_endpoint + "/members"
    def check_valid_status(self, status):
        choices = ['subscribed','unsubscribed','cleaned', 'pending']
        if status not in choices:
            raise ValueError("Not a valid choice for email status")
        return status

    def add_email(self, email,status = "subscribed"):
        self.check_valid_status(status)
        data = {
            "email_address": email,
            "status": status
        }
        endpoint = self.get_member_endpoint() 
        r =requests.post(endpoint, auth=("", self.key), data=json.dumps(data))
        return r.json()

    def subscribe(self, email):
        return self.add_email(email)
```

and my terminal showing this

```
[14/Feb/2020 21:15:38] "GET /admin/jsi18n/ HTTP/1.1" 200 3223
Internal Server Error: /admin/marketing/marketingpreference/add/
Traceback (most recent call last):
  "D:\software\shopw\marketing\models.py", line 35, in marketing_pref_update_receiver
    status_code, response_data = Mailchimp().unsubscribe(instance.user.email)
ValueError: too many values to unpack (expected 2)
```

please help me.

Comment: Well, your `Mailchimp.unsubscribe()` methods returns one object (`r.json()`). If that object isn't a 2-tuple, then python can't map it to `status_code, response_data`. Look into what `r.json()` is.

Comment: thank you so much @dirkgroten . i didn't write this  r.status_code, r.json()